# How to select everything that goes after #imageContent

Tags: imacros

I have this line of code

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#imageContent18>IMG" BUTTON=0
```

Number 18 always changes so i want to select everything that goes after #Content
i trued to do it likes this `#imageContent*`, but it's seems something incorrect in my syntactic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="[id^=imageContent]>IMG" BUTTON=0
```